# DNN 2SXC tokens how to add in editor

Tags: token, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm new to 2SXC I'm trying to inject basic content in the Wysiwyg editor, using a token, but have so far been unsuccessful. This is so I can easily add inline content. Like our operating hours are [Content:Operating Hours].

Using [Content:Title] is not working. What I'm I missing?
Using latest Dnn and 2sxc.
This could be either in a Basic content block already or in a plain normal content block.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

My best guess is that you are trying to insert other content-block into a rich-text field.

If this is what you are doing, then you should look at the [Inner Content feature](https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/tutorial-create-very-rich-text-inner-content-2-with-2sxc)

If you get the [Blog App](https://2sxc.org/apps/app/blog-v5-hybrid-for-dnn-and-oqtane) you can see it in action.

Comment: Please avoid link only answers

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I guess I'm looking for something like LiveTokens that I can inject global reusable content anywhere. Like a phone number or working hours or even a small code snippet. I wanted to see if 2sxc could do the same thing without having to purchase another module. Either way I'll certainly be using 2sxc (well done on a great module bytw) for reusable template blocks with Razor, mini apps and more.

Comment: Glad you like it ;).